# PowerShell - sort&move files by Edit date

Tags: powershell, sorting, subdirectory

Simple task. But can't realize.
I just need to take file from one directory (x) and move to another (z) + create there folder named "YYYY" (year of last edit), then, subfolder named "MM" (month of last edit).

So i find script and tried to adapt it for my needs. But, i can't run it succsesfully.
Here is code witch i took as example:

```
$files= Get-ChildItem -File «C:\Files\»
foreach ($file in $files) {
if ($file.lastwritetime -lt $lastweek) {
$file | Move-Item -Force -Destination { md («C:\Files\» + $_.LastWriteTime.ToString(«yyyy.MM») + «\» + $_.LastWriteTime.ToString(«yyyy.MM.dd»)) -Force}
}
}
```

So i made mine based on it:

```
 $files=  Get-childitem -path "c:\Files"
$files | foreach-object {Move-Item -Force -Destination { md ("C:\Files\" + $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy")+"\"+$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM"))}}
```

Please help me make it work!
Im not really good with powershell...

Answer (score 0):

Better not construct paths by concatenating strings with `+`. To avoid errors, use the `Join-Path` cmdlet for that.

Also I would advice not trying to cram that much in one line of code, because when it fails, it is really hard to debug.

Try

```
$path = 'C:\Files'
Get-childitem -Path $path -File | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $destination = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ('{0}\{1:D2}' -f $_.LastWriteTime.Year, $_.LastWriteTime.Month)
        $null = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory -Force
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $destination
    }
```

<sup>You can shorten the code by creating tyhe destination path like this: `$destination = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ('{0:yyyy\\MM}' -f $_.LastWriteTime)`, but then you have to remember to escape the backslash in the `-f` Format template string by doubling it</sup>